# Fisher's exact test for multidimensional contingency tables

Tags: fishers-exact-test, hypergeometric-distribution

I have a dataset that has 6000 instances, each with 8 boolean values.

```
mat = matrix(runif(6000*8) > 0.5, nrow=6000)
colnames(mat) = LETTERS[1:8]
mat = as.data.frame(mat)
multidimensional_cont_table = table(mat)
```

If I want to perform a exact fishers test on a 2 dimensional contingency table:

```
fisher.test(table(mat[,1:2]))
```

but how do I go about doing this for the multidimensional case?

What I am trying to ultimately do is ask: what unions in my venn diagram are overrepresented? i.e. which pairs (or triples, etc.) have higher counts than due to chance.

---

I found a solution called the super exact test:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/SuperExactTest/vignettes/set_html.html

I'm wondering if anyone could comment if this is the correct metric to use?

Comment: Why do you need specifically exact test for potentially such a big task for permutations? Is multidimensional asymptotic likelihood chi-square unacceptable?